# interface for fields in golang

Tags: inheritance, go

Let's say I have a struct which should be used as a result for an upload:

```
type uploadResult struct {
  Filename string `json:"filename"`
  Code string `json:"code"`
  Reason string `json:"reason"`
}
```

There will be other structs like this one, both having a field `Code` and another one called `Reason`. It would therefore be interesting to have something like a common interface (pseudo-go-code; this one doesn't work):

```
type apiResult interface {
  Code string `json:"code"`
  Reason string `json:"reason"`
}
```

Because I would like to call a function which extracts some common fields, but only those that are common:

```
func failExit(result apiResult) {
  fmt.Println(result.Reason)
}
```

So how would I rewrite it so that it does what I'm expecting?

Best regards

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should just be able to embed a struct with the common fields in the specific structs.

***Live demo:*** http://play.golang.org/p/7Ju-r-yE1-

```
type apiResult struct {
  Code string `json:"code"`
  Reason string `json:"reason"`
}

func failExit(result apiResult) {
  fmt.Println(result.Reason)
}

type uploadResult struct {
  Filename string `json:"filename"`
  apiResult // <-- embedded
}

func main() {
  var ul uploadResult
  ul.Code = "...some code..."
  ul.Reason = "The description"
  ul.Filename = "foo.txt"

  failExit(ul.apiResult)
}
```

So there shouldn't really be any need for interfaces in this situation. Just embed the `apiResult` in whatever structs need it.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot define fields in interfaces. Trying so results in `test.go:32: syntax error: unexpected name, expecting (` and 
`test.go:33: non-declaration statement outside function body`

Comment: @Atmocreations: Sorry, didn't change it to a struct. See the update. Though your error seems to come from running non-declaration code outside of a function, so it's not really related.

Comment: Okay thank you. How about the instantiation of such objects? Apparently, I cannot do this: `result := uploadResult{Code:"someCode", Reason:"This failed do to some reason"}`

Comment: @Atmocreations: Yeah, unfortunately the composite literal syntax requires an explicit struct syntax. `var ul uploadResult = uploadResult{
    apiResult: apiResult{
      Code: "...some code...",
      Reason: "The description",
    },
    Filename: "foo.txt",
  }`  http://play.golang.org/p/8GLEbuqPGK

Comment: And I actually don't want the `failExit` to be a member of `apiResult`

Comment: @Atmocreations: Where should it be a member? You could redefine it on every struct that embeds `apiResult` I guess, but why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72857/discussion-between-atmocreations-and-lye-fish).

Comment: It should actually not be a member of something. I've adapted your answer according to the results of our discussion. Now it works, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Long story short, Go interfaces don't allow fields to be declared because conceptually they deal with behavior not data. Fields are data.

There's a couple of ways to go about what you want to do:

Here's some examples on how to approach this:

This one uses an interface to expose the APIResult fields as part of the apiResponse interface: 
http://play.golang.org/p/ONLzvqlP5R

This one uses an interface to expose the APIResult as part of any Result struct that contains one:
http://play.golang.org/p/NzxPHhDls_

On that note, you could solve this by using composition by having `APIResponse` be a struct that has the common fields and then any other struct that needs those fields exports the `APIResponse` struct.

```
type APIResult struct {
    Code   string `json:"code"`
    Reason string `json:"reason"`
}

type UploadResult struct {
  Filename string `json:"filename"`
  APIResult
}

func failExit(result APIResult) {
  fmt.Println(result.Reason)
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/k85vTJoFRn